# WPF Ribbon Controls in Visual C# 2010

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, ribbon

I'm developing an application with Visual Studio 2010 in C# which is specified to have a ribbon style interface, thus I've downloaded Ribbon for WPF from Microsoft.

After creating a WPF Ribbon application though the toolbox Ribbon Editor items are all greyed out when viewed under show all. I've tried everything from resetting the toolbox to deleting the toolbox registry items and .tbd files as some other guides have shown, but I still can't access these items. I've also changed my target framework from ".NET Framework 4 client" to just ".NET Framework 4" to no avail and checked that RibbonControlsLibrary is correctly referenced.

Are there any suggestions to what I should do next or am doing wrong?

Comment: You may also have a look at this ribbon library, https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon

Comment: I am aware of it, but I was hoping to stick with the built in tools, I have a pretty tightly constrained dev environment. In the worst case I'll just directly edit the xaml.